# Parsing Api with Httparty NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Hi I am parsing JSON API from https://api.commissionfactory.com/V1/ via rake task

```
desc "run feed"
task :mr => :environment do
  include HTTParty
  url = 'https://api.commissionfactory.com/V1/Affiliate/Merchants?apiKey=fakekey&status=Joined'
  response = HTTParty.get(url).parsed_response

  response.each do |item|
    Vendor.find_or_create_by(name: item['Name'])
  end
end
```

I can get the json data but not parse it via response.each or response.map

When I try with the code above I get a

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

when I puts response I get the data below as expected:

```
{"Id"=>201, "DateCreated"=>"2014-04-10T10:47:35.747", "DateModified"=>"2017-06-11T00:00:32.11", "Name"=>"Tony's Furniture", "AvatarUrl"=>"https://c.url.com/io/39BD094A-24B5-4659-8A7A-FE6E023E9ED8.png"}
```

and I can manipulate the data via

```
response.map do |item|
    puts item['Name']
    puts item['Category']
    puts item['TargetUrl']
    puts item['Summary']
    puts item['TrackingUrl']
    puts item['AvatarUrl']
  end
```

but as soon as i try to create or save records i get the same issue.

Vendors Controller

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_vendor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /vendors
  # GET /vendors.json
  def index
    @vendors = Vendor.all
  end

  # GET /vendors/1
  # GET /vendors/1.json
  def show
    @products = @vendor.products.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /vendors/new
  def new
    @vendor = Vendor.new
  end

  # GET /vendors/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /vendors
  # POST /vendors.json
  def create
    @vendor = Vendor.new(vendor_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vendor.save
        format.html { redirect_to @vendor, notice: 'Vendor was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @vendor }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /vendors/1
  # PATCH/PUT /vendors/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @vendor.update(vendor_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @vendor, notice: 'Vendor was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @vendor }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /vendors/1
  # DELETE /vendors/1.json
  def destroy
    @vendor.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to vendors_url, notice: 'Vendor was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_vendor
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def vendor_params
    params.require(:vendor).permit(:name, :description, :Category, :TargetUrl, :Summary, :TrackingUrl, :AvatarUrl)
  end
end
```

Vendor Model

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :brands
end
```

While I have parsed xml data with nokogiri this is my first json parse with httparty. Can you please point out why I cannot seem to parse the data into the rails vendor db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from a mentor we were able to discover that the

```
include HTTParty
```

in my task

```
desc "run feed"
task :mr => :environment do
  include HTTParty
  url = 'https://api.commissionfactory.com/V1/Affiliate/Merchants?apiKey=fakekey&status=Joined'
  response = HTTParty.get(url).parsed_response

  response.each do |item|
    Vendor.find_or_create_by(name: item['Name'])
  end
end
```

was throwing the error. with its removal, the task passed.

As an older library, the include statement imports the entire library, which in this case threw the error and was not related to my needs.